# Currently i am trying tomake a EF database and I wunder why and how to get this is "NULL" away from my table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am currently trying to make a EF system with a few relations/FKs.

My classes looklik this :
I have an artikel class, a Location class and a prognoseclass that look like following:
[image]

[image]

[image]

After i run my "Package manager comandline" with a "fresh database" i get with seeded data Like this:

[image]

Now the question is : why is there a "Entry" Location_LocationId that has a NULL valll?

How can one get this away or shall it be there:??

If I havent provided enough data please let me know.

My system is working as i want to have it but i am desperate trying to "optimize" it and trying to get questions like this cleared out.

Comment: If I may give you unrelated advice: Go entirely English with your identifiers. After a while it feels much cleaner, more consistent and it is great training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use attribute ForeignKey.

```
[ForeignKey("Location")]
```

before "LocationId" property in "Prognose" class

You can read this tutorial http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx
If you want to make one to one relations in EF.

Comment: Aha - just your solution out but now i get this error in my PM-Console:

The property 'LocationId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.

Answer (score 1):

The [Key] on Prognose should be on the PrognoseId, not LocationId. 
Location should also be a public virtual property:

```
public class Prognose
{
  [Key]
  public int PrognoseId {get;set;}
  // ..
  [ForeignKey("Location")]
  public int LocationId {get;set;}
  public virtual Location Location {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answar and the changes as you mention is done.... BUT still get an error that i dont can solve...
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Prognoses_dbo.Locations_LocationId' on table 'Prognoses' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors. If more info is needed please let me know... going crazy ...:-(

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

in my class "locacaion" i did not have a nullabale value and the was somehow the solution.

[image]

and the prognose class look with the changes that you suggested:

[image]

Again thanks for the help and links:-)

Happy coding from here.